# gulp-sass import is silently failing

Tags: css, import, sass, gulp

I am trying to transpile a scss file using gulp-scss.
When i run the task it doesn't seem to pick up the imports.

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.src('./app/css/app.scss', {base: './'})
    .pipe(sass({includePaths:'./node_modules/foundation-sites/scss'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./web'));
```

**app.scss**

```
/*my custom styles*/
@import 'my-custom-styles';

// Sass utilities
@import 'util/util';

// Global variables and styles
@import 'global';

// Components
@import 'grid/grid';
etc.....
```

**app.css**

```
/*my custom styles*/
body{background:black;}
```

i am expecting app.css to be full of foundation code.
Any ideas?

Edit: i'm getting no errors even though ive tried adding error handling. 
**Console**

`[00:52:07] Using gulpfile ~/dev/rise-client/gulpfile.js
[00:52:07] Starting 'scss'...
[00:52:07] Finished 'scss' after 9.28 ms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i was importing foundation wrong.

You must `@import 'foundation';`
not all the components. :/

Working scss file

```
@import 'foundation';
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an error in your sources, try:

```
.pipe(sass(/* config */))
.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err); }))
```

Comment: Good idea.. unfortunately i just tried all sorts of error catching (including the one you suggested ) and no dice. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the files that you're importing](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/tree/master/scss) it doesn't seem like they are actually styling any elements by themselves. All they contain is variables and `@mixin` and `@function` definitions. Unless you actually reference those in your own **app.scss** file, nothing from your imported files will end up in your compiled **app.css**.

For example, if you reference [`$warning-color`](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/d6de501/scss/_global.scss#L109) in your **app.scss** like this:

```
@import 'util/util';
@import 'global';
@import 'grid/grid';

body {
  background:$warning-color;
}
```

You end up with a compiled **app.css** like this:

```
body {
  background: #ffae00;
}
```

So there's nothing wrong with your gulpfile. It's your SCSS that is at fault.